# Istream seekg() offsets and ios::end

Tags: c++, stream

When I type in is.seekg(0), it takes me to the beginning of my stream.  But, when I type in is.seekg(ios::end) it takes me to the second character.  Why does that happen.  I think my misunderstanding of this is rooted in a fundamental lack of understanding about how streams work.  I would think that when you provide the constant ios::end it would take you to the end of that stream.  But, it seems as though it moves you one character forward.

```
  cin.seekg(0, ios::end);
  int length = cin.tellg();
  cout << length << endl;

  cin.seekg(0);

  cout << cin.tellg();
```

When I input <  file containing "123456789"

The output is 10 0

Now if I do this :

```
  cin.seekg(ios::end);
  int length = cin.tellg();
  cout << length << endl;
```

The output is 2

Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

This code just works by accident

```
cin.seekg(ios::end);
int length = cin.tellg();
cout << length << endl;
```

the value `end` comes from an `enum seekdir {beg, cur, end};`, so `ios::end` just happens to be convertible to an integer with the value `2`.

It is just unfortunate that the parameter to one overload of `seekg` is an integer, so that the call turns into `cin.seekg(2)`. While technically valid code, this is definitely not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You are converting something of type `std::ios_base::seekdir` to the type `std::istream::pos_type`, and invoking the version of `seekg` that only takes one argument. That version of `seekg` moves the pointer to an absolute position, not a relative position.

`ios::end` is a logical position used for the relative offset, not an absolute position.

Answer (score 1):

You can't rely on STDIN being seekable.  This is because it can come from a number of sources, including pipes which are definitely not seekable.  Chances are it worked when you redirected the file because the STDIN got tied to a file stream.  I don't know if you can rely on that, but that's my guess.  I've never even considered seeking on STDIN.  I always consider it to be a pipe, even when it's not.  Same with STDOUT.  I wouldn't output something and then try to backtrack and 'overwrite' that output.  If you find yourself needing to seek in the standard streams, you should probably rethink your approach.